# Visual Studio Build Agent scripted setup

Tags: powershell, azure-pipelines, windows-scripting

I´m trying to automate VSTS Build Agent Setup (https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/actions/agents/v2-windows).

However there's an interactive step in the process. It´s a cmd script file which requires user's input. I tried to generate a TXT file with the settings, and run the script reading the input from that file:

```
.\config < settings.txt
```

But it didn´t work. I got that message:

```
Enter server URL > Enter authentication type (press enter for PAT) > Enter perso
nal access token > Cannot read keys when either application does not have a cons
ole or when console input has been redirected. Try Console.Read.
```

Is it possible to set up a build agent by script? Is there any way to "redirect" the console input in a such way that this `config.cmd` works perfectly?

Comment: You  just need to config the agent for once for future use. No matter config manually in interactive window or config automatically by adding the options (url, pat, pool, agent etc as thom said) at the beginning of configuration, both of them works. And the automatic configuration can only save a few seconds or minutes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Did you try passing --help to the Config.cmd

There are a number of examples below is a snippet of the examples:

### Unattended configure and unconfigure examples:

Remember to check return code when using unattended configuration

#### Unattend configuration for VSTS with PAT authentication

```
Win  : .\config.cmd --unattended --url https://myaccount.visualstudio.com --auth PAT --token <token> --pool default --agent myagent

Unix : ./config.sh --unattended --acceptteeeula --url https://myaccount.visualstudio.com --auth PAT --token <token> --pool default --agent myagent
```

#### Unattended configuration for on-premise TFS with integrated (Windows) and (Linux/OSX) negotiate authentication

```
Win  : .\config.cmd --unattended --url http://mylocaltfsserver:8080/tfs --auth Integrated --pool default --agent myagent

Unix : ./config.sh --unattended --acceptteeeula --url http://mylocaltfsserver:8080/tfs --auth Negotiate --username DOMAIN\USER_NAME --password MyPassword --pool default --agent myagent
```